# Polymer-3.x.. Can't able to bind value from the JSON through object reference to the paper-toggle-button

Tags: polymer-3.x

```js
//Properties
drivingEligibility:{type:Boolean,notify:true}
//EventListener 
driving(){
if (this.$.drivingEligibility.checked == true) {this.drivingEligibility = true;
       console.log(" drivingEligibility.value in if :" +this.drivingEligibility);
     }else{
        this.drivingEligibility = false;
       console.log(" drivingEligibility.value in else :" +this.drivingEligibility);
     }
   }
```

```html
HTML Code
<paper-toggle-button name="drivingEligibility" id="drivingEligibility" class="float-right" checked="{{drivingEligibility}}" on-change="driving"></paper-toggle-button>
```

Data is saving in the correct format.. but data is not binding to the element(paper-toggle-button)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the value of `drivingEligibility` in function. Its already bound. At:

```
<paper-toggle-button name="drivingEligibility" id="drivingEligibility" class="float-right" checked="{{drivingEligibility}}" on-change="driving"></paper-toggle-button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cant-able-to-bind-value-from-the-json-through-object-referen?file=index.js)

Comment: hi HakanC, try to get the data from backend and bind through the object(state). while binding the data it,s not binding to the paper-toggle-button eg: suppose the drivingEligibility value is true from the backend but, I am getting the false because I have set the default value is false in ready function. So plz help me out . is it possible

Comment: @mounika, please check the Demo link again. I set and object outside of custome element. And after when changed, returned back to root the object value.